# kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using kafka2.11-0.11.0.1, scala 2.11, and spark 2.2.0. I added following jars to eclipse's java build path:

```
kafka-streams-0.11.0.1,
kafka-tools-0.11.0.1,
spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0,
spark-streaming-kafka_2.11-1.6.3,
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0,
kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1.
```

And my code is below:

```
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import kafka.api._
import kafka.api.ApiUtils._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._


object KafkaExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[*]", "KafkaExample", Seconds(1))

    val kafkaParams = Map("bootstrap.servers" -> "kafkaIP:9092")

    val topics = List("logstash_log").toSet

    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc,kafkaParams,topics).map(_._2)

    stream.print()

    ssc.checkpoint("C:/checkpoint/")
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

It is very simple code for just connecting spark and kafka. However, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:86)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:94)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:85)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.findLeaders(KafkaCluster.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLatestLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
    at com.defne.KafkaExample$.main(KafkaExample.scala:28)
    at com.defne.KafkaExample.main(KafkaExample.scala)
```

Where am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I tried "metadata.broker.list" instead of "bootstrap.server" but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have too many Kafka dependencies loaded up, and the ones picked up at runtime aren't binary compatible with the version Spark expects.

Your *actual* problem is the `PartitionMetadata` class. In 0.8.2 it looks like this (which is what you get from `spark-streaming-kafka_2.11-1.6.3`):

```
case class PartitionMetadata(partitionId: Int, 
                             val leader: Option[Broker], 
                             replicas: Seq[Broker], 
                             isr: Seq[Broker] = Seq.empty,
                             errorCode: Short = ErrorMapping.NoError) extends Logging
```

And in > 0.10.0.0 like this:

```
case class PartitionMetadata(partitionId: Int,
                             leader: Option[BrokerEndPoint],
                             replicas: Seq[BrokerEndPoint],
                             isr: Seq[BrokerEndPoint] = Seq.empty,
                             errorCode: Short = Errors.NONE.code) extends Logging
```

See how `leader` changed from `Option[Broker]` to `Option[BrokerEndPoint]`? That is what Spark is yelling about.

You have to clean up your dependencies, all you need is (if you're using Spark 2.2) is:

```
spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0,
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0
```

Comment: Thx for quick response Yuval. When I remove spark-streaming-kafka_2.11-1.6.3 (import .....KafkaUtils) gives error. When I remove kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1 top 3 imports give error. So, I can't use methods in main. I removed top 2 jars, it is okay. But with this 5 jars, I get this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/network/Send. I am totally confused. I cant remove them, if I include, still doesnt work. :(

Comment: If you only use `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0` and `spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0,` you get an error? Thats unlikely.

Comment: Is my code wrong? I think I need kafkautils. And it is in kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1. So I need stringdecoder and it is in kafka stream. If i dont need that 2 code part I can remove them. In above case I cant. Actually, as you guess, I am beginner, and need a quick guide to connect kafka and spark. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAktaş `KafkaUtils` resides inside `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0`. Again, as I've said, remove all other jar dependencies.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov. thanks. i was having the same error. your solution made me to rectify it. you were right that we need to point only these dependency jar(spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.3.0,spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.0,spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0).